# Changing binding mode in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding-mode

I'm making a small application, it's a form that reads from a data source, I want to use it for editing and adding new records.
so the default binding mode for the textboxes in the form is `TwoWay` mode, so the user can edit an existing record, but I want to add a Checkbox that when checked, it marks the data in the textboxes as new, and then adding them to the data source, so I need to change the binding mode to `OneWay`,
to my knowledge, to do this in code I need to create a new `Binding` object, that I will have to set properties like `Source` that doesn't change:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = ViewModel;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeString");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
```

So is there a way to change only the Binding mode in code?

**EDIT**

some further explanation of the application:

In the form there's a combobox that is bound to a `List<Book>`, there  are 3 `TextBox`s, their `Text` properties bound to the `DataContext` object of their container which itself set to the `SelectedItem` of the `Combobox`.
When I added the `ReadOnly` property as described in the answer, when I check the checkbox I can't change the text in the textboxes.

..

Thanks!

Comment: You are right, you need to create new binding. But. Can you explain why do you want to do this in code-behind? You can set new binding in XAML in trigger that looks at the checkbox `IsChecked` value. Also I sure that you don't need to change `Mode` of binding. Let it be `TwoWay` but don't update backing fields when some property that bound to `IsChecked` equals true.

Comment: interesting, could you please post it as an answer, with code example?

Comment: OK, I've posted it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change `Mode` of binding. Just correct your view-model logic.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    private bool _readOnly;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (ReadOnly || value == _text)
                return;

            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }

    public string ReadOnly
    {
        get { return _readOnly; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _readOnly)
                return;

            _readOnly = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReadOnly));
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML bind `IsChecked` property of your `CheckBox` to `ReadOnly` property.

Comment: it will not update the UI but still binds to the source

Comment: Yes. And what is wrong with it? It solves your task without changing of binding. If this solution is not appropriate describe why.

Comment: I changed the setter to this, `if (title == value) return;
                title = value;
                if (ReadOnly) return;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));`
please see the amended question

Comment: OK... But as far as I understand you want to prevent source updating in case of `ReadOnly == true`. I made this decision from your intention to use `Mode=OneWay`. Now it seems that you want to update source anyway and you need just prevent UI updating.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is "Yes, but".  The Mode property of Binding has a setter.  So it appears that you can set the mode of an existing binding like so...

```
       BindingExpression be = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        Binding b = be?.ParentBinding as Binding;
        if (b != null)
        {
            b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        }
```

However if you do this you will get in every case the exception...

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.
```

So the only way to accomplish what you want is to create a new binding based on the old binding while changing the mode.  Then replace the old binding.

```
           BindingExpression be = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        Binding b = be?.ParentBinding as Binding;
        if (b != null)
        {
            Binding b2 = new Binding();
            b2.Path = b.Path;
            b2.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b2);
        }
```

This is less than ideal because for completeness you would need to copy the converter, the converter parameter and so on, but this is the best you can do.